# Can python be integrated into HTML, JavaScript... Online?

Tags: python

I have a python multiplayer game which I want to host online. So far I have only seen online games which use some kind of user downloaded library (such as a flash or the java runtime virtual box) of course, many gamers won't have python installed. For the game, it is using the multiplayer by the library socket, and the tcp protocol. I hope someone has some framework, or even just some links thats could help.

Thanks

Comment: LMGTFY: http://www.skulpt.org/

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks for the quick reply, that looks great.  Would it be compatible with my libraries pygame, socket, time, math, random, though? Apart from that looks great!

Comment: I doubt that it runs PyGame, but it is kind of cool.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a thought, since I know nothing about your game, but have you heard of [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)? It is a Python-based web framework.

This may not solve the graphical portion of your game, if it does not interface well with Flash, HTML5, or JavaScript. But this would allow you to reference your Python classes and game libraries directly in your webpage's framework.

Comment: This is a comment for vsergeyev, i apolagise, i am still learning stackoverflow!               I just checked out django, first of all, thanks for the reply. I don't think i will use it though, because with all my libraries, (see above) and django looking like it isn't python based (I actually don't know a lot of JavaScript) I could how ever learn html5 (I already know HTML)  which I could use with django. I was going to do this anyway, as I want to host online games. But for that, I may as well by adobe flash...

Answer (score 0):

Does packaging your game is an option? If yes maybe http://www.tidesdk.org/ will help.
As far as I know it allow to include python runtime in installer.

Also I have seen python implementation in javascript - http://www.skulpt.org/